# Recommended ways to build a responsive table

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, styled-components

What are the recommended ways to build a responsive table?

I would like to do this table responsive below 991px,

So for 768px-991px, I would like to show only 3 columns with no scroll to the right as right now I'm having this issue. How can I hide the last column in a responsive way?

And for 375px-768px breakpoints, I would like to show 2 columns. Any suggestion?

```
<table class="table">
                <tr>
                  <td>Title</td>
                  <td>
                    <img src="./..." alt="" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <img src="./..." alt="" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <img src="./..." alt="" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <img src="./..." alt="" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Color</td>
                  <td>
                    <strong>Blue</strong>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <strong>Red</strong>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <strong>Green</strong>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <strong>Purple</strong>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Lorem</td>
                  <td>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
                    typesetting industry.
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
                    typesetting industry.
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
                    typesetting industry.
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
                    typesetting industry.
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                  <td>
                    <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                  <td>8.93ibs</td>
                  <td>8.93ibs</td>
                  <td>8.93ibs</td>
                  <td>8.93ibs</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `display: none` to `tr td:nth-last-child(n)` to the respective media queries.

Like so -

```css
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  tr td:nth-last-child(1),
  tr td:nth-last-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  tr td:nth-last-child(1),
  tr td:nth-last-child(2),
  tr td:nth-last-child(3) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td>
      <img src="./..." alt="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="./..." alt="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="./..." alt="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="./..." alt="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Color</td>
    <td>
      <strong>Blue</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>Red</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>Green</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>Purple</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </td>
    <td>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </td>
    <td>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </td>
    <td>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>
      <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
    </td>
    <td>
      <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
    <td>8.93ibs</td>
    <td>8.93ibs</td>
    <td>8.93ibs</td>
    <td>8.93ibs</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How is that approach responsive? You are hiding possibly important information from the user only because he is in a smaller screen, like discriminating the kind of information he has access to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Bootstrap (which I assume you do because of that class="table") then you can apply d-none, d-sm-block, extra classes to achive this goal, like:

```html
<tr>
 <td>Color</td>
 <td>
 <strong>Blue</strong>
 </td>
 <td class="d-none d-md-block">
 <strong>Red</strong>
 </td>
 <td class="d-none d-lg-block">
 <strong>Green</strong>
 </td>
 <td class="d-none d-lg-block">
 <strong>Purple</strong>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Or if you want to use your custom classes (for more custom break points) then you may refere to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020595/hide-columns-in-responsive-table-using-css/17020701)